# m1 mac, python assertion failure and crashes when using osx as backend in matplotlib & jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, nsevent

The error occurs when I was using jupyter notebook

I am using a m1 macbook pro with monterey 12.1, lastest version as this is being written

Here is my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib osx
```

Here is the error message

```
2021-12-23 18:16:19.185 python[25121:1046786] *** Assertion failure in +[NSEvent otherEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:subtype:data1:data2:], NSEvent.m:740
2021-12-23 18:16:19.199 python[25121:1046786] *** Assertion failure in +[NSEvent otherEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:windowNumber:context:subtype:data1:data2:], NSEvent.m:740
```

This message just repeats hundards of times and shows a recursion error in the end and crashes

Here is the recursion error message

```
Exception ignored on calling ctypes callback function: <function stop at 0x122abff70>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/strategy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ipykernel/_eventloop_macos.py", line 107, in stop
    _triggered.set()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/strategy/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 544, in set
    self._cond.notify_all()
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/strategy/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 381, in notify_all
    self.notify(len(self._waiters))
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/strategy/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 361, in notify
    if not self._is_owned():
  File "/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/strategy/lib/python3.9/threading.py", line 274, in _is_owned
    if self._lock.acquire(False):
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

While other interactive backends works fine, e.g. nbAgg

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question but add some more info to it, as I went into this in more detail:

When trying to create data plots that are not inlined in a notebook, there is some erroneous behaviour. Either the error described above happens, or the plots are shown and a crash report dialog pops up.

This was tested with the following setup:

macOS Monterey 12.1 (M1 ARM processor)
Python: 3.9.1
matplotlib: 3.5.0
Jupyter: 1.0.0
notebook: 6.4.7
(using a virtual environment)

**Example 1:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib osx
plt.plot(np.arange(100))
```

*This leads to the error described in the stack overflow link mentioned above. The cell with the call to plot() seems to be evaluated repeatedly. Sometimes, a plot window will show but get stuck, due to the repeated calls.*

**Example 2:**

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QtAgg')
plt.plot(np.arange(100))
```

*This runs through smoothly, except for the fact that no plot is shown. The last cell’s call returns [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x12f076bf1>] though. Adding plt.show() does not help either. With TkAgg backend, the same behaviour is observed. Interestingly, when using MacOSX as a backend, I would expect, that the error from Example 1 would occur, but the behaviour is the same as with the other backends…*

It remains unclear to me, how plots can be opened externally to the notebook without any errors under the conditions described above.

Comment: Please add comments in the comments section below the question (First get the required minimum score for placing comments).